# Using Named Pipes in Bash created in a C Program

Tags: bash, c, curl, fifo

I have a C code that takes a rather large input. At every iteration, it processes a small chunk of it and it should send that processed chunk to S3 using curl. In the end, it will generate a number of those small chunks and the large input would be completely processed. Where I am having problem is the part where bash script calls the named pipe I use to send the processed chunk to S3 in separate.

How can I call the bash script in C and how can I send the data inside named pipe to curl using bash?

I'll only share the related part of the code to keep it clean.

```
#define FIFO_NAME "my_fifo"
int i,j,k;
char *d_ptr; //dummy pointer for frame set
int res;
/* create the FIFO (named pipe) */

if (access(FIFO_NAME, F_OK) == -1) {
    res = mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0777);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create fifo %s\n", FIFO_NAME);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
res = open("test_fifo", O_WRONLY);
d_ptr=(char *) compressed_queue;
if(m_ptr-m_ptr_initial==0 | m_ptr-m_ptr_initial>MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH-FLENGTH*sizeof(float) | number_of_frames>MAX_FRAME_NUMBER)//sends message when the chunk is ready and adds its prefix
{

    for(j=0;j<m_ptr-m_ptr_initial;j++)//sends message as stdout
    {

        /* write to the FIFO */
        write(res, m_ptr_initial[j], sizeof(char));

    }
    if (res != -1)
        (void)close(res);
```

Also, the bash script is the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    TIMER=renesas-$(date +"%H-%M-%S").txt
    echo $TIMER
    ./Compression
    my_fifo| curl -X PUT --data-binary @- 54.231.19.24/{somePublicBucket}/device1/${TIMER}
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bugs in your code:

1. `write(…, sizeof(char));` will only write "sizeof(char)" bytes (= most likely 1 or 2 bytes) to the FIFO, and not the size of the buffer as you probably intended
2. `my_fifo |` will not read any data from the FIFO; you'll need to `cat` it at least.

Since the call to `write`will block until the script reads the data (and vice versa!), I suggest to put the write operation and the execution of the script into two different processes or threads (there are other possibilities as well, e.g. non-blocking write; it all depends on your intended design). The following example demonstrates the principle, using the `fork` system call for simplicity:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define FIFO_NAME "./my_fifo"

int main() {
    int res, fifo, pid;
    char *str = "Hello World!\n";

    /* Fork this process into a reader and a writer */
    fprintf(stderr, "Forking process\n");
    pid = fork();
    assert(pid >= 0);

    if (pid == 0) {
        /* The reader calls a shell script supposed to read the data from the FIFO */
        printf("Starting shell script\n");
        system("./tst.sh");
    }
    else {
        /* Create FIFO */
        fprintf(stderr, "Creating FIFO\n");
        remove(FIFO_NAME);
        res = mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0777);
        assert(res == 0);

        /* Open FIFO */
        fprintf(stderr, "Opening FIFO\n");
        fifo = open(FIFO_NAME, O_WRONLY);
        assert(fifo != 0);

        /* The writer opens the FIFO and writes some data to it */
        printf("Writing to FIFO\n");
        res = write(fifo, str, strlen(str));
        assert(res > 0);
        close(fifo);
    }
}
```

And the shell script `tst.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Started shell script"
cat ./my_fifo
```

The output of the C program is:

```
Forking process
Creating FIFO
Opening FIFO
Starting shell script
Started shell script
Writing to FIFO
Hello World!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Guido! I've had one problem after this. When I used your code and placed write inside the for loop, I kept getting assertion errors right after write function calls. Since at each for loops iteration I write one character from my char array, I decided to make its size the size of char. Is calling write multiple times a wrong practice? Also, can I simply use cat ./my_fifo like a file to pipeline its data to curl?

Comment: @Furkanicus You can either write `cat ./my_fifo`, or `curl .... < my_fifo`. The fifo is used like a file. Regarding the `write` call, I changed my example to `printf("Writing to FIFO\n");
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
            res = write(fifo, str + i, sizeof(char));
            assert(res > 0);
        }` to output one character at a time as well and it worked. Did you do something dramatically different?

Comment: Hey Guido, I'm not exactly sure what was wrong, but I assume it was my pointer arithmetic at fault. Anyway, the problem is fixed. Thank you so much!